# How do I find out hard disk model and serial number in amazon machine?

Tags: linux, filesystems, amazon-ec2

when check in local machine `/proc/scsi/scsi` file it contains

```
Attached devices:
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: ATA      Model: ST3160215AS      Rev: 3.AA
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: HL-DT-ST Model: CD-ROM GCR-H11N  Rev: V613
  Type:   CD-ROM                           ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
```

it shows model details **Model: ST3160215AS**

similarly

```
cat /sys/block/sda/device/model
```

This file also gives same model details

```
ST3160215AS
```

like this how do i find out in amazon machine ?

same code is not working in amazon machine why?
Please help me

Comment: Is `lshw` available?

Comment: What do those files contain on the amazon machine? Do you have root access? Can you install software? Do you have access to tools such as `lshw` or `hwinfo`?

Comment: @Fiximan @terdon `lshw` & `hwinfo` commands are not there. And i have root privilege, i can install s/w

Comment: Don't you have /sys and /proc file on Amazon machine ?

Comment: EC2 instances have two types of storage and Amazon is slowly getting rid of the instances with attached local storage.  Most of the newer instance classes are coming with EBS only configuration and you won't be able to get any information re: them since they are network attached.  For the older instances you should be able to get the hardware info if you install the corresponding packages.

Comment: @SHW `/proc` & `/sys` file are there but what i mention above, those files aren't there .

Comment: Actually @galaxy even the local (ephemeral) hard drives are still virtualized -- they're just local to the host machine instead of network-attached.

Comment: @shas, everything is virtualized in EC2.  Perhaps we could help you solve your problem if you would explain why this information would be useful.

Comment: @ Michael - sqlbot i want calculate something, in that formula i need to used RPM(rotation per  minute) so if get **ST3160215AS** this type of num from file so i will get RPM and further its easy to  calculate.